# what does "XMP over SOAP protocol" mean?

Tags: web-services, soap, interface, xmp

what is the meaning of the following line ?

"The interfaces are built using XMP over SOAP protocol"

....the interfaces referes to webservices.

Comment: Are you sure it's `XMP` not `XML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMP stands for "Extensible Metadata Platform".  It's a standard created by Adobe, and it lets you store metadata on documents that describe said documents.

SOAP is a method for transporting objects between different computers.  It uses XML documents.

I suspect XMP on SOAP means that the SOAP XML documents use XMP to hold embedded metadata.